# Using Bokeh to have multiple live plots in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I'm trying to use Bokeh to have several live plots in a Jupyter notebook. I understand that I cannot use push_notebook() since it will only update the last figure. Is there another way to do it as of today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push_notebook` updates the last cell by defatult, if you don't pass it an argument. But it also accepts a "notebook handle" that `show` returns when it renders a cell.

```
# in one cell
p = figure(**opts)
r = p2.circle([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
h = show(p)

# in a different cell
r.glyph.fill_color = "white"
push_notebook(handle=h)
```

See the [Basic Usage](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/notebook_comms/Basic%20Usage.ipynb) example notebook in the GitHub repo.